# Scala Swing Box Subscribes Multiple Events

Tags: swing, events, scala, foreach

I'm writing a GUI in Scala, and I've run across a strange problem while trying to register Button Events in a `foreach` statement: It should be that for every element *object<sub>i</sub>* in a list of objects (*object<sub>0</sub>* ... *object<sub>n</sub>*), a corresponding Button *x = button<sub>i</sub>* is retrieved and a given Box is subscribed to it with `box.listenTo(x)`. When the Button is pushed, some action related to the *object<sub>i</sub>* should be performed (in this case, `println("Event triggered: " + event)`):

```
import scala.swing.ComboBox
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer
import scala.swing.Button
import scala.swing.event.ButtonClicked
import scala.swing.Action
import scala.swing.SimpleSwingApplication
import scala.swing.MainFrame
import scala.swing.GridPanel
import scala.swing.BorderPanel


object EventSet extends SimpleSwingApplication  {

    object PhoneKeyEvent extends Enumeration {
        val Key1 = Value("1")
        val Key2 = Value("2")
    }

    /* Constants */

    private val DisplayHistory = Buffer[String]()   

    private val KeypadKeyEvents = List(
        PhoneKeyEvent.Key1, PhoneKeyEvent.Key2)

   private val PhoneKeyEventButtonNames = Map(
        PhoneKeyEvent.Key1 -> "1",
        PhoneKeyEvent.Key2 -> "2"
        )

    /* End constants */        


    private var PhoneKeyEventButtons = Map[PhoneKeyEvent.Value, Button]()

    private def createDisplay() : ComboBox[String] = {

        new ComboBox(DisplayHistory) {
            // Listen to keypad keys
            // Get the set of all keypad key events
            val keypadEvents = List(PhoneKeyEvent.Key1, PhoneKeyEvent.Key2)
            println("keypadEvents: " + keypadEvents)
            keypadEvents.foreach({ event =>
                println("event: " + event)
                // Listen to each button representing a keypad key event
                var keypadEventButton = PhoneKeyEventButtons(event)
                println("keypadEventButton: " + keypadEventButton)
                listenTo(keypadEventButton)
              reactions += {
                  case ButtonClicked(keypadEventButton) => {
                    // TODO: fix strange bug here: adds all possible inputs
                    println("Event triggered: " + event)


//                        selection.item = selection.item + event
                  }

              }


            })
        }

    }

    private def createPhoneControllerPanel() : BorderPanel = {
        new BorderPanel() {
            val keypadControlPanel = createPhoneKeyEventTypeControlPanel(KeypadKeyEvents)
            add(keypadControlPanel, BorderPanel.Position.Center)

            add(createDisplay(), BorderPanel.Position.North)   


            focusable = true
            requestFocus
        }
    }

     /**
     * Creates a new {@link Button} for a given {@link PhoneKeyEvent} and adds
     * the button to the global map of such buttons to their respective events;
     * that means multiple buttons cannot be created for the same key event.
     */
    private def createPhoneKeyEventButton(phoneKeyEvent: PhoneKeyEvent.Value) : Button = {
        // Only one button can be created per key event
        require(!PhoneKeyEventButtons.contains(phoneKeyEvent),
            {System.err.println("A Button for the PhoneKeyEvent " + phoneKeyEvent + "has already been created.")})

        val keyEventButtonName = PhoneKeyEventButtonNames(phoneKeyEvent)

        val result = new Button(Action(keyEventButtonName) {
            println("Key event button pressed: " + phoneKeyEvent)

        })

        // Add the button to the map of all created key event buttons
        PhoneKeyEventButtons += phoneKeyEvent -> result  
        return result

    }

    private def createPhoneKeyEventTypeControlPanel(keyEvents : Iterable[PhoneKeyEvent.Value]) : GridPanel = {
        new GridPanel(4, 3) {


            // Get the intersection of all key events of the given type and the events with button names
            keyEvents.foreach(phoneKeyEvent => contents += createPhoneKeyEventButton(phoneKeyEvent))
        }

    }

    override def top = new MainFrame {

        contents = createPhoneControllerPanel()


    }

}
```

However, I get some very strange behaviour, where clicking any Button results in *all* such object actions are triggered -- See the program output:

```
keypadEvents: List(1, 2)
event: 1
keypadEventButton: scala.swing wrapper scala.swing.Button$$anon$1[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=
javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@7633f09,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,de
faultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14]
,paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,te
xt=1,defaultCapable=true]
event: 2
keypadEventButton: scala.swing wrapper scala.swing.Button$$anon$1[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=
javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@7633f09,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,de
faultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14]
,paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,te
xt=2,defaultCapable=true]
Key event button pressed: 1
Event triggered: 1
Event triggered: 2
Key event button pressed: 2
Event triggered: 1
Event triggered: 2
```

I'm completely at a loss as to why this is happening; I'm quite new at Scala anyway, so it's quite unfamiliar territory, but I've tried fiddling with a lot of stuff and snooped around in the Swing source code, and still clueless... how can *every* value of a reference inside of a loop be used in every iteration? or how can every event be triggered by Swing at once? or...?

**Edit:** Here are two minimised versions, both of which behave differently:

```
import scala.swing.SimpleSwingApplication

object ButtonEvents extends SimpleSwingApplication  {

import scala.swing.Button
import scala.swing.event.ButtonClicked
import scala.swing.Action
import scala.swing.MainFrame
import scala.swing.FlowPanel

override def top = new MainFrame {

    contents = new FlowPanel {

        val button1 = new Button(Action("1") {
        println("Button 1 pressed")

    })
        contents += button1
        val button2 = new Button(Action("2") {
        println("Button 2 pressed")

    })
        contents += button2
        val buttons = List(button1, button2)
        buttons.foreach({ button =>
            listenTo(button)
            reactions += {
                case ButtonClicked(button) => {
                    println("Event triggered: " + button.text)
                }
            }
        })


    }


}
```

}

Prints:

```
Button 1 pressed
Event triggered: 1
Event triggered: 1
Button 2 pressed
Event triggered: 2
Event triggered: 2
```

And a version which seems to behave correctly (but I'm not sure why):

```
import scala.swing.SimpleSwingApplication


object ButtonEvents extends SimpleSwingApplication  {

    import scala.swing.Button
    import scala.swing.event.ButtonClicked
    import scala.swing.Action
    import scala.swing.MainFrame
    import scala.swing.FlowPanel

    override def top = new MainFrame {

        contents = new FlowPanel {

            val button1 = new Button(Action("1") {
            println("Button 1 pressed")

        })
            contents += button1
            val button2 = new Button(Action("2") {
            println("Button 2 pressed")

        })
            contents += button2
            val buttons = Map("1" -> button1, "2" -> button2)
            buttons.foreach({ eventButton =>
                listenTo(eventButton._2)
                reactions += {
                    case ButtonClicked(eventButton._2) => {
                        println("Event triggered: " + eventButton._1)
                    }
                }
            })


        }


    }

}
```

Prints (correct):

```
Button 1 pressed
Event triggered: 1
Button 2 pressed
Event triggered: 2
```

Comment: tl;dr - you should boil down the code to the essence of the problem

Comment: The problem is that when I try to "boil down the code" I get different (but related) behaviour, and I don't know where the difference is: Here are two different versions which behave differently from above:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
reactions += {
  case ButtonClicked(keypadEventButton) => {
```

you are creating a new `val keypadEventButton`and assigning it to whatever is inside `ButtonClicked()`. Changing the line to  `case ButtonClicked(abstractButton)` will still work and display same problem.

I'm guessing you are expecting this to match the use of `keypadEventButton` on the preceding lines. You probably want to create one reaction and then use the `abstractButton` to tell what button has been pressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help: I got it to behave the way I want it to by replacing the `reactions` block with

`reactions += {
                  case ButtonClicked(abstractButton) => {
                   if(abstractButton == keypadEventButton) {
                   println("Event triggered: " + event)
                   }    
                  }       
              }`

Answer (score 1):

@andy is correct. A good IDE like IDEA will highlight "suspicious shadowing by a variable pattern", since you're binding a new variable in the pattern match. Scala allows you to shadow variables as much as you want, within nested code blocks, for instance:

```
scala> val a = 1; {val a = 2; println(a)}; println(a)
2
1
a: Int = 1
```

So what does the following return?

```
val a = 1
2 match {
  case a => "it was 1"
  case _ => "something else"
}
```

It returns `"it was 1"` because `a` is shadowed. Now try:

```
2 match {
  case `a` => "it was 1"
  case _ => "something else"
}
```

This returns `"something else"` because we used backticks to refer to the value of he previously defined variable. (Also try this where the variable begins with a capital letter...)

So you just need to add backticks, i.e.

```
case ButtonClicked(`button`) => {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the shadowing tip; however, in the given case with ButtonClicked, I get a "stable identifier required, but keypadEventButton found" message. Still, I found a solution using this info and andy's (see above).

Comment: @errantlinguist that's because you declared `keypadEventButton` as a `var`. Don't use `var` unless you really need it. Declare it as a `val` and it should be OK. You could alternatively phrase what you wrote above better using a guard: `case b: ButtonClicked if b == keypadEventButton => ... `